# Django e-commerce project as beginner rabbitmq installing problem on windows 10

Tags: django, windows, rabbitmq, e-commerce

Kindly help but keep it simple as I am a beginner.
Django e-commerce project, installed Erlang 64-bit and rabbitmq on windows 10, still when I try to install rabbitmq on bycharm terminal using :
apt-get install rabbitmq .......It gives me this :   'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Then tried replacing apt-get with choco and got the same response

Comment: It's unclear what you are intending to do? Why do you need rabbitmq?

Comment: `apt-get` is for unix based systems only, sir. Follow the steps described [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows,to install RabbitMQ using Chocolatey, run the following command from the command line or from PowerShell:

```
choco install rabbitmq
```